# How To Upgrade Custom Workflow WSP Using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, powershell, upgrade

I have a custom Visual Studio workflow.  There are hundreds of instances of it running in a site collection.  I now need to update it.  The workflow consists of some custom task forms and the workflow itself and I have WSP files built for all of these.

Should I use Install-SPSolution or Update-SPSolution so that the existing instances of the workflow keep running without being affected by the update?

Answer (score 2):

`Update-SPSolution` is what you need, assuming you did not add any new features to the workflow. If you did, you need to use `Install-SPSolution`

Check out this link referencing upgrading workflows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543659.aspx

In both, the DLLs and the files will be updated in the GAC the same way, but if the solution has changed the ID of a feature, changed scope of a feature, changed version of a feature, changed elements.xml, or has a new Property element to the Feature.xml file, then a complete retraction and reinstall will have to be performed--remove the workflow solution and remove it from the farm entirely before Installing.

Comment: could you explain the difference between Update-SPSolution & Install-SPSolution with regard to what happens to the DLL's in the GAC?

Comment: @motionpotion see my edit.

Comment: In the case where a complete retraction & redeployment happens then the running instances of the workflow will stop because the existing version of the DLL will no longer be available in the GAC?

Comment: Workflows that are running should stay intact with the old definition. Check out this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f3ae607b-a16c-477e-9c2f-f0dc76f6849f/updating-sharepoint-2013-workflow-in-production-environment-not-during-development?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: But if the old WSP is retracted then does that remove the old versions of DLL's for the workflow & custom approval forms? Thus meaning the running instances cannot find the DLL version in the GAC? This is what is not clear to me.

Comment: If you use `Update-SPSolution` then all the existing workflow instances will remain intact.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the work flow's wsp is little shady. You can use the Update-spsolution to upgrade it but what about the running instance of the Workflow? and it also depend what you change in the wsp.

Check this for more information.

[Upgrade custom workflow in SharePoint](http://kmsnet.blogspot.com/2013/07/upgrade-custom-workflow-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: this doesn't give me a definitive answer to the question.  The running instances must stay working in my case.